# Initializing pointer to a pointer that's dynamically allocated in function

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I am passing a pointer to a pointer into a function to dynamically allocate it as I am trying to store the data received from a socket. It works find for one request, the second one usually results in a seg fault. Valgrind complains: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) referring to my response pointer.

How can I initialize the pointer or what can I do to make this safe? And is it correct to free it in the main function?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char * response;
    char readbuf[BUFFSIZE + 1] = "";
    //here I read some data into readbuff which I will send to the server below
    handle_request_data(readbuf, &response);
    //do some stuff with response, send to another socket
    free(response); // can I do that?
}

int handle_request_data(char * readbuf, char ** response) {
    //create tcp socket, connect to it and send readbuf to server

    int recv_total = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE + 1] = "";
    *response = malloc(BUFFSIZE + 1);
    while ((tmpres = recv(sock_tcp, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0)) > 0) {

        if (recv_total > 0) {
            //need more memory for buffer
            *response = realloc(*response, BUFFSIZE + recv_total + 1);
        }
        memcpy(*response + recv_total, buffer, tmpres);
        recv_total += tmpres;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Add a `*response [recv_total] = '\0'` to the end of the function; otherwise the buffer would not be NUL terminated. 2) Also: tmpres could be -1; which should be handled seprately.

Comment: What is buffer? readbuf ??

Answer (score 1):

1) Q: Initializing pointer to a pointer that's dynamically allocated in function

Caveat: You should initialize the pointer only once - inside the function. If you (re)initialize it elsewhere, you risk a memory leak, or some other catastrophe.

2) Q: is it correct to free it in the main function?

Sure :).  But same caveat: free it only *once*.  And, ideally, get in the habit of setting it to NULL after you've freed it.

3) Q: It works find for one request, the second one usually results in a seg fault.

My guess is that you're *stepping* on the pointer somewhere in your code.

Q: Where is "buffer" defined?  Are you sure you're not overwriting it (and clobbering your "response" pointer) in recv()?

Q: Where exactly is the segfault occurring?  Can you step through that part of the code in a debugger?

Please post back what you find!

Comment: forgot to put the buffer into the code snippet, it's there now. the seg fault is a result of a buffer overflow i believe, but I do not know why it occurs. I am handling some structs that contain char[]. These are passed as pointers into other functions and are then corrupted by what was stored in my response variable.

Comment: Your edit just confuses things: you're now allocating readbuf[] in main(), passing it into handle_request_data(), creating a *NEW* buffer, and ignoring the first readbuf[] altogether.  But the main thing: be *SURE* you're not overwriting the buffer in "recv()", or overwriting "response()" in "memcpy()".  Using a debugger is highly recommended.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

First, the easy one:

> And is it correct to free it in the main function?

Why wouldn't it? You couldn't do anything else anyway.

Second, the hard part: well, you should try debugging your code using a debugger. At first glance, it seems fine, but we never know. Are you using multithreading? Are you sure there are no race conditions present? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

What is buffer? Inside of `handle_request_data` is not defined. A global?
Did you mean readbuf ?? This paramter is not used.

Comment: @enpo. Good. Now you have the definition of buffer inside handle_request_data. It is working now? It was the problem? Or only the first problem? And you can eliminate the first argument of the function and the definition in main of readbuf.